# Firebase realtime database phone security rules

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I need some help with securing my database.

Those are my security rules:

[image: firebase rules and playground]

I've tried this code to give access to each user to read and write his own data:

```
{
"rules": {
     "Users":{
         "$user":{
             ".read": "auth.token.phone_number==$user",
             ".write": "auth.token.phone_number==$user",
          }
      }    
  }
}
```

My database looks like this (i'm using phone numbers instead of uid):

[image]

but for some reason when I run the firebase rules playground with a given auth.token.phone number that equals to the exact location I gave for example i get read option denied.

and it happens also within my app with my app can you guys help me to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

In provider type ::Choose Custom
And In payload use :

{
"provider": "anonymous",
"uid": "******************",
"token":{
"phone_number":"**********"
}
}

Rules are:

"$phone":{ ".read":"auth!==null && auth.token.phone_number===$phone", ".write":false } }

Answer (score 0):

create a new data path admins and store the phone number as a child and do this. sorry if this didnt work as i am also a beginner

```
  root.child('admins').child(auth.token.phone_number)
```

Comment: Ya but then it's like auth!=null because when the user exsists anybody can read or write to the $user